# React SSR: hot-module-replacement(HMR) or live-reload for frontend code changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to work out a `koa2` + `react` + `webpack` SSR project. I'm currently still working on development environments and stucked in choosing hot-module-replacement or live-reload for frontend code changes.

#### HMR

`webpack-dev-middleware` + `webpack-hot-middleware` + `react-hot-loader3`, if code changes, frontpage will automatically do HMR without page reloading, so you don't revisit server-side router and re-server-render again.

#### Live-Reload

Basically just a little modification for HMR, I just added `reload=true` for webpack entry configuration **(webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000&reload=true)**. The biggest difference is when code changes are detected browser will auto reload current page so you will revisit server router and re-server-render everything.

#### Question

Since I have little practice on SSR development, it would be nice if you could tell me which way is better or what key points I should consider. Thanks!